# Clojure: How can I get the value of a text field when clicking a button created using Hiccup?

Tags: angularjs, clojure, hiccup

In my Clojure program (using Hiccup), I'm looking to get the value of a text field when a user clicks on a button, and then append that date to a URL. I've attempted to use "ng-model" from AngularJS, however this results in the following error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 11: /dashboard/{{date}}
```

The code I currently use is below:

```
(text-field {:class "form-control" :ng-model "date"} "date" date)
[:a {:class "btn btn-primary" :href "/dashboard/{{date}}"} "Submit"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like hiccup is converting the string of your link into an URI and this is causing a problem.

An easy way to get out of the problem would be to avoid using that helper for angular links and directly creates an a tag:

```
[:a {:class "btn btn-primary" :href "/dashboard/{{date}}"} "Submit"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I get the value from my text field though? Do I use the text-field's ID that I gave it?

Comment: That is related to angular, you need to make the html rendered from clojure compatible with angular to make it work